# Can't run python scripts in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, windows-10

I have been using Jenkins for a few years and recently bought a new Windows 10 PC. I installed Jenkins 2.89.2, Visual Studio 2017 and Python 3.6 and copied several Jenkins jobs from my previous Windows 7 PC.

The problem that I encountered was that all the python scripts in the free-style Jenkins jobs now do nothing.

I have similar command-line batch files which run these python scripts which work just fine in a command window on the new PC.

I have also checked the file associations with `ftype`, and ended up changing it:

```
ftype Python.File
Python.File="D:\Python36_64\python.exe" "%L" %*
```

My work-around is like this:

Example line which worked under Windows 7:

`CreateBuildNumber.py`   <= uses PATH to find this file, then file associations to run python

Replacement line need to work under Windows 10:

`python .\Scripts\CreateBuildNumber.py`  <= uses PATH to find python.

How can I avoid explicit paths in my scripts?

**Update:**

```
D:\project>assoc | findstr -i python
.py=Python.File
.pyc=Python.CompiledFile
.pyd=Python.Extension
.pyo=Python.CompiledFile
.pyw=Python.NoConFile
.pyz=Python.ArchiveFile
.pyzw=Python.NoConArchiveFile

echo %PATH%
D:\Python36_64;D:\Python36_64\Scripts;.\Scripts;"C:\Program Files\CppCheck";C:\windows\system32
```

**Further Info**

I removed .\Scripts from the %PATH% and re-ran the job, having also moved demo.py into .\Scripts, now instead of doing nothing there is the error:

```
'demo.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This means that Windows **IS** looking for and finding python scripts, but is failing to execute them. Why would windows not take the next step and use file associations to find an executable program to run, taking the file as a parameter?

**Update:**

Now everything works as it should and I don't know why.

I recently started using a different job on Jenkins that I had neither run nor touched for over two years and that one just worked without modification. I have since gone back over the job in question and reverted all the changes and this one works as well.

My guess is that Windows 10 has been patched.

Comment: Are you able to run the python file (*CreateBuildNumber.py*) directly from console (when Python.File is set)? In *Jenkins* are they executed (or at least attempted)?

Comment: I started setting up my Win-10 PC by running my batch files from the console and everything was fine. I then installed Jenkins and realised from the console logs that the python files weren't running (Some of them have version numbers: `file.py --version` and I wasn't getting a version number) I have left Jenkins with a line: `demo.py` which should just print 'demo.py' and it still does nothing.

Comment: Can't you set the working directory in Jenkins for the python script?

Comment: The `demo.py` script is on the current working directory and that doesn't work. I've put that in there as a flag to tell me if it starts working.

Comment: Maybe PATH isn't set the same way by the installer on Win10 as it did on Win7?  This blog post says a little bit about it https://anthonydebarros.com/2015/08/16/setting-up-python-in-windows-10/

Comment: PATH isn't the issue since I reset the PATH at every step in the freestyle project. And that's the reason the replacement command-line (`python .... .py`) works ok as it just uses the PATH to find python.

Comment: Could it be that your associations are not correct? What does `assoc | findstr -i python` give you?

Comment: I will check that soon, once my PC has been repaired. :-(

Comment: you can add env variables only for you or for all in .bash_profile and .bashrc respectively. With this you can avoid the explicit paths. hope this helps.

Comment: What is `.bash ... `?

Comment: If you `echo PATH` right before calling the script, does it contain the script's directory?

Comment: @Hetzroni: That I will double check right after my PC is repaired :-(  But it should be, considering how many years its been working on previous machines.

Comment: @CaptainWhippet: update shows the `assoc` results.

Comment: @Hetzroni: Update shows results of `echo %PATH%` which includes the vital `.\Scripts` element which is where python scripts are stored.

Comment: So... magic? http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2019/01/18/its-not-magic/?

Comment: @VonC: Yes! Somewhere within a two hour window something changed.

Comment: running these toolsets on windows would be kinds of painful, ideally, everything run in jenkins needs to be validated at your 'cmd' first.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that "demo.py" gives the message '...is not recognized as an internal or external command' doesn't convince me that your script is recognized as executable.  If I type 'turkey.abc' into a command prompt window I get the same error, and I don't have a tool for executing '.abc' files.

I see two possibilities here:

1) In batch scripts, executable extensions sometimes must appear in an environment variable called PATHEXT.

In the Jenkins batch script, add a "set" command near the top of the script to dump the environment variables for your running script into your Jenkins build log (you can remove the set command after this is debugged).  Run the build.  Look not only for the definition of PATH, but also at PATHEXT.  Is ".py" one of the extensions listed there?

I have experienced this problem with Perl scripts.  However, I'm wimping out on claiming this definitely since in testing on my Windows 10 home PC I am successfully executing .py scripts even without it being in PATHEXT, so it's something to try but it may not be this.

2) Another possibility is that the environment in which your service is running is different than the environment you get when you open a command prompt on your desktop (because the Jenkins service runs as a different user than the one you log in as.)

Adding "set" to your Jenkins batch commands will help debugging this too, since it will show you the environment your Jenkins script is running in.  Then you can examine PATH to see if your script folder is being found.

It is also possible that the file associations for Python were installed for your user only, not for all users (i.e., in HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).  That is harder to dump into your Jenkins log - the 'reg' command would do it, but it will take you a number of tries to get everything you need.  You might be able to figure it out by just examining the registry.  Search for ".py" - if it occurs in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE that is not it; if it occurs in HKEY_CURRENT_USER that is at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your issue but you shouldn't have a relative path in your PATH environment variable.

Can you try again after having removing **.\Scripts** from the PATH variable? (don't forget to open a fresh new terminal do get the new %PATH% value)

Comment: What terminal? This is a batch file that Jenkins, running as a service, creates and runs itself. It seems that Win10 just ignores some files on the command line when in a batch file running in a service. Also, why not a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your PATH variable doesn't include the paths of you python scripts. You need the full path of the `Scripts` directory. Not the relative path `.\Scripts`.

Comment: I'll try that, but note that other batch files stored in `.\Scripts` are also 'called' and work ok. I used a relative path because I didn't know where on my system Jenkins would be running and so a relative path worked out well on my previous two computers. Also see the **Further Info** edit to my question.

Comment: Absolute path of the `Scripts` folder made no difference, sorry.